# ImportError: cannot import name 'Option' from 'discord'

Tags: python, discord.py

I can't run my code, because of this
Can someone help me ?

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'Option' from 'discord'
```

My imports are

```
import discord
import datetime
from discord import Option
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import MissingPermissions
from discord_components import Button, Select, SelectOption, ComponentsBot, interaction
from discord_components.component import ButtonStyle
from discord_slash import SlashCommand
from discord_slash.utils.manage_commands import create_option
```

Comment: Has it worked in the past? Have you looked where your discord package is installed on your machine?

Answer (score 0):

That's happening because you just installed an external API wrapper so now you aren't using `discord.ext` I would recommend you remove pycord or you will have to rewrite all of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Heiiiiii,

I know the problem and it really gets on my nerves....

I have found an order....

```
pip uninstall dicord -y

pip uninstall py-cord -y

pip install discord

pip install py-cord

pip uninstall discord -y
```

I hope I could help you.

- Clara

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You need to install the developer version of pycord...

```
pip install git+https://github.com/Pycord-Development/pycord
```

or

```
py -3 -m pip install -U py-cord
```

Comment: Thank you, it helped me, my version was outdated
But now i'm facing another problem `from discord.ext import commands
ImportError: cannot import name 'commands' from 'discord.ext' (unknown location)`